# Redirection.config cannot read due to insufficient permissions

Tags: iis, iis-7, configuration, permissions, windows-server-2008

I keep getting the following error:

```
c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set site /site.name:"WebVTS" /+bindings.[prot
ocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:webvts.mprinc.com']
ERROR ( message:Configuration error
Filename: redirection.config
Line Number: 0
Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
. )
```

I'm trying to add a hostname to an https: site in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008.  I added IUSR read/modify to my web.config file. But can't seem to figure out where and what is redirection.config?

Comment: Related post - [Cant add bindings to IIS programatically - redirection.config permissions (with a video!)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24352251/465053)

Answer (score 3):

Click Start-> type "Command Prompt"-> Right click on Command Prompt program->"Run As Admin".
Then run Command line programs, it should work.
Also you need to have Admin rights on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you run AppCmd.exe from an elevated command prompt.